# How to access a javascript variable in Shiny which is dynamically updated based on Input by the User

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

I want to access the value stored in a JavaScript Variable within a js file and use it in shiny for further processing

I am using "Shiny.onInputChange" but the value returned is null even though the variable created in JavaScript is a global variable. Is there any other way to access the variable.

Comment: `Shiny.onInputChange` works fine. You should post your code if you encounter a problem.

Comment: I specifically want a variable to just store the latest value of the variable as and when the value changes in JavaScript. I can't share the code here due to company policies. Can someone give me a general example of how this works.